# Hide/show div using jquery .height()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to get div element height and hide another div if it contains given max height. if not show the div. So I tried this way.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fpw187L5/)

assigned my max height to a variable with if else conditions.

```
var tallest = 60;

 if (height > tallest) {
     $('van-page-read-more').hide();
  }

   else {
    $('van-page-read-more').show();
  }
```

Not working at all. What am I missing here?

Comment: You never set the variable `height`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 issues

1) you did not set height variable

2) and you for got to add `.` before

```
$('.van-page-read-more').hide();
```

```js
$('.van-page-read-more').click(function() {
  $(".campervan-info-list").toggleClass("campervan-info-expand");
});

var tallest = 60;
if ($(".campervan-info-list").height() > tallest) {
  $('.van-page-read-more').hide();
} else {
  $('.van-page-read-more').show();
}
```

```css
.campervan-info-expand {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="campervan-info-list campervan-info-expand">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat, orci sed faucibus semper, ante risus auctor ligula, ultricies cursus odio nulla ac leo. Vivamus auctor volutpat porta. Morbi venenatis luctus turpis, quis laoreet ante bibendum sit
  amet. Aliquam vel massa sed orci gravid

  <br>

  <br>lectus id commodo. Aliquam ultricies justo et magna porttitor tincidunt. Nam ut condimentum turpis. Praesent rutrum ut turpis non finibus. In eu egestas augue, vitae viverra mi. Nunc molestie enim est, luctus volutpat ante laoreet interdum. Proin
  id fermentum magna. Sed semper mauris urna, non pulvinar quam rhoncus ut. Integer ultrices sodales odio vitae pharetra. Duis a enim nec velit rhoncus pharetra eu a sapien. Donec sem enim, ornare vitae tellus eu, porta ultricies ligula. Suspendisse in
  nisi a metus sagittis iaculis. Nullam eu eros eu urna
  <br> lacinia lacinia. Quisque pharetra metus neque, in venenatis sem scelerisque eu. Proin blandit, purus vel volutpat scelerisque, ex orci varius nunc, ut consequat turpis mauris non magna. Mauris pellentesque mauris mi, e
</div>
<br>
<a class="van-page-read-more">Read more</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
$("div.class").each(function() {
  if($(this).height() > tallest) {
     $(this).hide();
  }
  else {
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enought reputation to comment @Just code solution.
You need to wrap it to function

```js
  $('.van-page-read-more').click( function() {
    $(".campervan-info-list").toggleClass("campervan-info-expand");
    showOrhide();
} );

var tallest = 60;

function showOrhide(){
 if ($(".campervan-info-list").height() > tallest) {
     $('.van-page-read-more').hide();
  }
    
   else {
    $('.van-page-read-more').show();
  }
  
};
```

```css
.campervan-info-expand{
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.van-page-read-more{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="campervan-info-list campervan-info-expand">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat, orci sed faucibus semper, ante risus auctor ligula, ultricies cursus odio nulla ac leo. Vivamus auctor volutpat porta. Morbi venenatis luctus turpis, quis laoreet ante bibendum sit amet. Aliquam vel massa sed orci gravid
  
  <br>
  
  <br>lectus id commodo. Aliquam ultricies justo et magna porttitor tincidunt. Nam ut condimentum turpis. Praesent rutrum ut turpis non finibus. In eu egestas augue, vitae viverra mi. Nunc molestie enim est, luctus volutpat ante laoreet interdum. Proin id fermentum magna. Sed semper mauris urna, non pulvinar quam rhoncus ut. Integer ultrices sodales odio vitae pharetra. Duis a enim nec velit rhoncus pharetra eu a sapien.

Donec sem enim, ornare vitae tellus eu, porta ultricies ligula. Suspendisse in nisi a metus sagittis iaculis. Nullam eu eros eu urna
<br>

lacinia lacinia. Quisque pharetra metus neque, in venenatis sem scelerisque eu. Proin blandit, purus vel volutpat scelerisque, ex orci varius nunc, ut consequat turpis mauris non magna. Mauris pellentesque mauris mi, e
</div>
<br>
<a class="van-page-read-more">Read more</a>
```